# How to Make a TODO list item when a database cell matches today's date

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to create a todo list looking for any cell that matches today's date on either agreement, start or due date.

```
<% @project.where("project_date_agreement + project_date_start + project_date_due > ?", Date.today).each do |tasks_today| %>
     <ul>
        <li>Item Due Today</li>
     </ul>
 <% end %>
```

Any help getting me in right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: I did not understand what you want. Can you be more clear?

Comment: I clarified my question, didn't realize I made it so confusing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `OR` conditions in your where clause. Properly speaking this would be in your controller.

```
@projects = Project.where('date_agreement = ? OR date_start = ? or date_due = ?', Date.today, Date.today, Date.today)
```

In your Project Model you might want to create a field that say's what's due...

```
def due_because
  due_array = []
  due_array << 'Agreement date' if date_agreemnt == Date.today
  due_array << 'Start date' if date_start == Date.today
  due_array << 'Due date' if date_due == Date.today'
  due_array.join(', ')
end
```

Then in your view you would iterate over the `@projects`

```
<ul>
  <li>Items Due Today</li>
  <% @projects.each do |project| %>
    <li><%=project.name%> <%=project.due_because%></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. And thanks for the extra info on labeling. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if you asking one row and different column, how about if you combine with table

```
<% @tasks = @projects.where("date_agreement = ? AND date_start = ? AND date_due = ?",Date.today ,Date.today, Date.today) %>
<table>
<tr>
  <ul>
    <% @tasks.each do |task| %>
      <td>
        <li><%= task.check_box :item_due  %></li>
      </td>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</tr>
</table>
```